# EF Core Migration Error with MenuTableID1 Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a project using Entity Framework Core, and I'm encountering an issue during migration operations. The relevant migration files include `MenuTable` and `BasketTable`.

When executing the relevant part in the API, I encounter the error

> Invalid column name 'MenuTableID1'

Upon checking the related migration files, I couldn't find anything related to 'MenuTableID1'. What could be the issue?

1. `mig_add_basket_table`

   ```
   public partial class mig_add_basket_table : Migration
   {
       protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
       {        
           // Baskets tablosunu oluşturur.
           migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Baskets",
                columns: table => new
                        {
                            BasketID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                                            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                            Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false),
                            Count = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                            TotalPrice = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false),
                            ProductID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                            MenuTableID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true) // Bu satırda nullable olarak değiştirildi.
                        },
                constraints: table =>
                        {
                            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Baskets", x => x.BasketID);
                            table.ForeignKey(
                                name: "FK_Baskets_MenuTables_MenuTableID",
                                column: x => x.MenuTableID,
                                principalTable: "MenuTables",
                                principalColumn: "MenuTableID",
                                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict); // Bu satırda Cascade yerine Restrict olarak değiştirildi.
                            table.ForeignKey(
                                name: "FK_Baskets_Products_ProductID",
                                column: x => x.ProductID,
                                principalTable: "Products",
                                principalColumn: "ProductID",
                                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                        });

        //Index'leri oluşturur.
        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_MenuTables_MenuTableID",
            table: "MenuTables",
            column: "MenuTableID");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Baskets_MenuTableID",
            table: "Baskets",
            column: "MenuTableID");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Baskets_ProductID",
            table: "Baskets",
            column: "ProductID");

        // MenuTables tablosuna foreign key ekler.
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_MenuTables_MenuTables_MenuTableID",
            table: "MenuTables",
            column: "MenuTableID",
            principalTable: "MenuTables",
            principalColumn: "MenuTableID");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        // MenuTables tablosundan MenuTableID sütununu kaldırır.
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_MenuTables_MenuTables_MenuTableID",
            table: "MenuTables");

        // Baskets tablosunu kaldırır.
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(name: "Baskets");

        // Index'leri kaldırır.
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_MenuTables_MenuTableID",
            table: "MenuTables");

        // MenuTables tablosundan MenuTableID sütununu kaldırır.
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "MenuTableID",
            table: "MenuTables");
    }
   ```
2. `mig_add_menu_table`

```
public partial class mig_add_menutable : Migration
{
     protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     {
         migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
             name: "MenuTables",
             columns: table => new
             {
                 MenuTableID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                     .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                 Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                 Status = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
             },
             constraints: table =>
             {
                 table.PrimaryKey("PK_MenuTables", x => x.MenuTableID);
             });
     }

     protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     {
         migrationBuilder.DropTable(
             name: "MenuTables");

     }
}
```

Comment: Do you update your database

Comment: I've already tried . The error persists even after updating the database.

Comment: You are creating a relationship through foreign key `"FK_MenuTables_MenuTables_MenuTableID"`, which is incorrect since a foreign key cannot reference itself. Please share your model code. 
It suggests that there is a reference to a column named `MenuTableID1` somewhere in your code, check the database , project code and migration history to find more details.